# Mocking delete method

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I want to implement delete method with validation and test it:

```
    @Override
    public boolean delete(Long id) {
        final Entity byId = repository.findById(id);
        if (byId != null) {
            repository.delete(byId);
        }
        final Entity removed = repository.findById(id);
        if (removed != null) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Test
    public void deleteTest() throws Exception {
        // given
        final Entity entity = new Entity(1L);

        Mockito.when(repository.findById(1L))
                .thenReturn(entity);

        // when
        final boolean result = service.delete(1L);

        // then
        Mockito.verify(repository, times(1))
                .delete(entity);
        assertThat(result, equalTo(true));
    }
```

But now Mockito is mocking object "removed" in service and method returns false. How can I test it?

Comment: You are calling `repository.findById` twice in your code, so you would need `Mockito.when(repository.findById(1L)).thenReturn(entity).thenReturn(null)`

Comment: It works. Thanks!

Comment: Note: `if (removed != null) return false; return true;` is better written as `return removed == null;`.

Comment: But as a more general question: why *wouldn't* `repository.delete` cause the element not to be null next time you try to find it? It seems that repository is defective if its implementation doesn't guarantee that already. As in, you seem to be testing the wrong unit here: test this in the unit tests of the repository class, not this class. Assert that `repository.delete` was called in your test, by all means, but don't rely upon the implementation of that delete method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I can see from your code, you are calling the method `repository.findById` twice. But you are not mocking that behaviour in your test. 
You need to use `thenReturn` twice, first time with `entity` and then with `null`

```
Mockito.when(repository.findById(1L)).thenReturn(entity).the‌​nReturn(null)
```

With you existing code, when you do `final Entity removed = repository.findById(id);`, the `remove` gets the assigned with `entity` and not null.